# Constructing a net convergent in Mackey topology

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence, topological-vector-spaces, weak-topology

Given a Banach space $X$ . Let $F\in X^{**}$ . We know that closed unit ball $B(X)$ is w*-dense in $B(X^{**})$ due to Goldstein's theorem . In paper

*Rodríguez Palacios, Angel*, [**A note on Arens regularity**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/qmath/38.1.91), Q. J. Math., Oxf. II. Ser. 38, 91-93 (1987). [ZBL0617.46053](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0617.46053).

they mention that together with Mackey-Arens theorem and Goldstein's theorem, we can find a bounded net $(x_\alpha)$ in $X$  such that it converges to $F$ in Mackey topology $\tau(X^{**},X^*)$.

Its direct consequence of Goldstein's theorem to find a bounded net convergent to $F$ in w*-topology. But I cannot think how to construct one which is convergent in Mackey topology $\tau(X^{**},X^*)$.

Answer (score 1):

The Mackey-Arens theorem says that the Mackey topology $\tau(X^{**},X^*)$ is a (in fact, the finest)locally convex topology on $X^{**}$ so that the dual of $(X^{**},\tau(X^{**},X^*))$ is $X^*$ (more precisely, consist only of evaluations in points of $X^*$) which also holds for $(X^{**},\sigma(X^{**},X^*))$. The Hahn-Banach theorem thus implies that the closures of convex sets in both spaces coincide so that $B(X)$ is Mackey-dense in $B(X^{**})$.

Comment: Thank you so much @jochen

Comment: You are welcome.